# Problema con Servicios en WCF

Tags: c#, visual-studio, soap, servicio, wcf

Estoy aprendiendo a realizar servicios SOAP con .NET usando el framework WCF. Sin embargo, al compilar me da el siguiente error. Y no entiendo el motivo.

```
tiene "netcoreapp3.1" como destino. No puede hacer referencia a este un proyecto con ".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" como destino.
```

El archivo .csproj es este:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Prueba.WCF.SOAP\Prueba.WCF.SOAP.Dominio.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System.ServiceModel">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\System.ServiceModel.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Muchas gracias!

Comment: por el mensaje de error, me da a entender que tienes dos proyectos y uno referencia al otro, hay incompatibilidades entre framework y core, es por eso que te salta esa excepcion

Comment: Deben usar ambos el mismo framework? Puedo hacer que usen ambos frameworks?

Comment: No se puede utilizar WCF en NET CORE (el que conocemos de NET Framework), pero hace un par de dias salio esto que es para que nos "duela" migraciones o que sea escalonada [CoreWCF 1.0 has been Released, WCF for .NET Core and .NET 5+](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/corewcf-v1-released/) pero lo ideal que vayas mirando gRPC